# Iterator to iterate over a generator

Tags: python-3.x, iterator

I am parsing an XML file, one of xml tag has a structure like this:

```
<product>
     <item seq="division-sec">Division</item>
     <item seq="dept-sec">Dept Info</item>
     <item seq="label01">Label 01</item>
     <item seq="label02">Label 02</item>
     ...
     <item seq="labelN">Label N</item>
     <item seq="date-mfg">27-11-2017</item>
     <item seq="date-exp">28-11-2019</item>
</product>
```

I have written a generator function to access product labels in a sequence:

```
def product_labels(xmlpage):
    #... parsed xml here
    for item in xmlpage:
       #-- process item for validation such as case sensitivity, etc
       yield item # ("division-sec", "Division")
```

Now I'm looking for a function or may be an iterator class, which would allow me to get first, last, prev, next and search methods on it:

```
class ProdcutReader(object):
     def __init__(self, product_labels):
       self.product_labels = product_labels

     def __iter__(self):
        return self

     def __prev__(self):
        return prev(self.product_labels ) #-- Dont know how to do this :(

     def __next__(self):
        current = self.current(next(self.product_labels))
        return current

     def current(self, obj=None):
         if not obj:
            return self.first()
         return obj

     def first(self):
         return list(self.product_labels)[0]   

    # search by label seq 
    def search(self, seq):
       # Not sure if this is the correct way
       for i in self.product_labels:
           if i[0] == seq:
              self.current(i)
              return i
    ... # With some more methods (if search works I can have some more methods)
```

So assume I need to use that object, it should work like this:

```
from product_reader import ProdcutReader as Reader
>>>r = Reader(product_labels)
>>>r.first()
("division-sec", "Division")
>>>r.last()
("date-exp", "28-11-2019")
>>>r.current()  # Let us say current is ("label01", "Label 01")
("label01", "Label 01")
>>>r.next() # or next(r)
("label02", "Label 02")
>>>r.prev()
("dept-sec", "Dept Info")
>>r.search("date-mfg") # This should also set the searched as r.current()  
("date-mfg", "27-11-2017")
```

If I can get how to write for prev, next and search I will be able to write remaining methods like, first, last, current etc.

Comment: post a test case showing expected result on calling `prev()` , `nex()`, `first()` etc methods

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - Thanks for suggestion, edited my post.

Comment: why should `def current(self, obj=None)` method accept `obj` argument? what's the reason?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - That was a typo, edited!

Comment: Iterators **only go forward**. There is no support for first, or last or previous elements, because then you'd have a *sequence*. Iterators are memory efficient access-to-one-thing-at-a-time series that only move in one direction.

Comment: If you want random access, either convert your generator to a list (`list(yourgen)`), or build your own iterator class that keeps track of the previous and first items. I'd not provide access to the last, because then you suddenly have to store all items up to the last in memory.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Thanks, actually your suggestion makes sense. but we have to show the total products (count) available on the UI along with a provision to navigate among the product pages. Which made me to look for the methods like first, next, prev, last, length etc.

Comment: @Laxmikant: so you want to produce batches of results. Perhaps you should parse this out to a database instead and let that worry about producing counts and paging? I don't know how long this information should be available for.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - We have client data in the XML format, putting such data in the database would be an extra overhead I believe, so not using database. Eventually we just have to update the XML if user updates the product.

Comment: @Laxmikant: the database would be an implementation detail, a cache. You are already coding up a lot of the database functionality, it'd just be simpler and more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

<del>You apparently need random access to any element at any time. To my eyes, I don't see why you don't simply use a list.</del>

<del>If you need the current/next/previous functionality without having to keep track of a counter variable, you could still base your construct on a list:</del>

```
class ProductReader(object):
    def __init__(self, product_labels):
        self.generator = product_labels
        self.active_generator = self.generator()
        self.element = None
        self.cur = -1

    def at_n(self, index):
        if self.cur > index:
            self.active_generator = self.generator()
        while len(self.storage) < index+1:
            self.element = next(self.active_generator)
        self.cur = index
        return self.element

    def current(self):
        if self.cur > -1:
            return self.element

    def last(self):
        try:
            while True:
                self.element = next(self.generator)
                self.cur += 1
        except StopIteration:
            return self.element

    def first(self):
        return self.at_n(0)

    def next(self):
        return self.at_n(self.cur+1)

    __next__ = next

    def prev(self):
        return self.at_n(self.cur-1)

    def search(self, query):
        oldcur = self.cur
        self.active_generator = self.generator()
        for i, element in enumerate(self.generator()):
            if query in element:
                self.cur = i
                self.element = element
                return element
        self.at_n(self.cur)  # reset to old state
        return None
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I could have an html page content along with its css, images, fonts extracted from a zip in one of variable for each product. so refraining myself from putting data for all products in the list. I want only one product at a time.

Comment: That means that you'd have to restart the generator every time you want to go back, do a search, etc. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: (edited same comment)
Yeah, I feel that is the only way at the moment. Kindly let me know if you have any other solution to this.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect this, I think this should work.

Comment: This assumes that re-creating the iterator object will yield the same objects again. That's not a guarantee that iterators can make.

Comment: It is one Laxmikant is apparently making. If you can't guarantee that and don't want to save the retrieved elements, I don't see a solution.

Comment: @L3viathan - Yeah, we are not planning to store any of the generator object  because user would less likely to navigate among all the products. He would stick on one product page at a time for long time say for (around for max up to half hour) and most probably he would exit the system once he update the product. 
We are providing a feature to navigate other products to check the difference between the product to product (let us say to compare product  attribute through his eyes by navigating the page first, next, prev, last etc)